# Размер Landing Page

Tags: html, css

Сколько должен быть размер лэндинга? у меня оно весит 7.5мб - это много? слышал что  размер лэндинга максимум должен быть 2 мб, а у меня 7.5мб. Картинки все сжал до максимума

Comment: Чем меньше, тем лучше. По моему субъективному мнению ни одна страница никакого сайта не должна весть больше одного мегабайта, пожалейте людей с мобильным интернетом

Comment: 7.5 – дохренища. Но если действительно много картинок и нет способа их оптимизировать (не сжать), то надо делать подгрузку в процессе, чтобы входная точка весила как можно меньше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал проверять сайт на загрузку здесь: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

И от этого уже отталкиваться.
Там, чуть ниже, тебе укажет что не так с твоим сайтом и что желательно оптимизировать.